# $\sqrt{y + 1} - \sqrt{y - 1} = \sqrt{4y - 1}$. Find the value of $y$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I tried this way
Squaring both sides

$(y+1)+ (y-1) - 2\sqrt{(y+1)(y-1)}=(4y-1)$

$1-2y =2\sqrt{(y+1)(y-1)}$
Again squaring both side.

$1+4y^2-4y =4(y^2-1)$
$4y^2-4y+1=4y^2-4$
$y=5/4$

But on putting the value result was.
1=2.
Which was wrong. 
I want to know where is the mistake.

Comment: When you square equation's sometimes you introduce new roots, which werent a root of the original equation, an example take $x = 1$ squaring would bring $x^2=1$ which has two roots $x=1,-1$ but $ -1 $ isnt the root of the original equation.

Comment: It would help if you used [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to render your maths. So for example the first line would be `$1-2y=2\sqrt{(y+1)(y-1)}$` which renders as $1-2y=2\sqrt{(y+1)(y-1)}$.

Comment: All of your calculations are correct. See @mrtechtroid 's comment. Your deductions show that "if there is a $y$ that satisfies the original equation, then it satisfies $y=5/4$", but they don't show that $y=5/4$ indeed satisfies the original equation. Indeed, you have shown that $y=5/4$ does not satisfy the original equation. So the correct conclusion is that there is no $y\in\mathbb{R}$ that satisfy the original equation. Indeed you can show that RHS>LHS for $y\ge 1$.

Comment: Graph the left hand side and the right hand side to see that the 2 do not intersect. Thus $5/4$ cannot be a solution.

Answer (score 5):

Consider function on LHS, $\sqrt{y+1} - \sqrt{y-1}$. It is not defined for $y<1$ and has a maximum value at $y=1$ as it is a decreasing function beyond $y\ge1$. Hence, its maximum value is $\sqrt{2}$.

On the other hand, RHS $\sqrt{4y-1}$ is an increasing function and is defined only for $y\ge \frac{1}{4}$.
At $y=1$, RHS is $\sqrt3$, which is greater than the maximum value of LHS.

Hence, LHS and RHS never meet at any point. The equation has no solution. See the graph for clarity.

[image]

Coming back to your question, it is important to note that when you square an equation, it can introduce additional roots. Consequently, the presence of this extra root in the resulting equation is what you are observing, which was not present in the original equation.

Answer (score 2):

Here we have

$\displaystyle \sqrt{y+1}-\sqrt{y-1}\leq \sqrt{y+1}<\sqrt{4y-1}$

Which is true when $\displaystyle y>\frac{2}{3}$

Above equality hold when $y=1$

So equation has no solution

Answer (score 1):

Another way, for $y=1$ equality doesn't hold and for $y>1$

$$\sqrt{y + 1} - \sqrt{y - 1} = \sqrt{4y - 1} \iff \frac2{\sqrt{y + 1} + \sqrt{y - 1}}=\sqrt{4y - 1} $$

$$\iff \sqrt{(4y - 1)(y+1)}+\sqrt{(4y - 1)(y-1)}=2$$

but

$$f(y)=\sqrt{(4y - 1)(y+1)}+\sqrt{(4y - 1)(y-1)} \ge f(1)=\sqrt 6>2$$